# conditional Segue in Dynamic Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cell

Another noob question but I could really do with some help on this one. I am looking for a way to have a list of cells in a dynamic prototype table view and each cell to go to a new view controller. I have managed to do this to about 75% :/. Basically I have made it work but it always loads the first cell first because its reuse identifier is called cell. Is there a way to make each one just load the View Controller I want? (code below)

Thanks
Sam

Edit 1: I have changed code to how it now looks below. But the Alton Barnes view controller is still loading in front of which ever cell you click and want to see.

```
import UIKit

class LocalAttractionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var Locations = ["Alton Barnes White Horse","Avebury","Barbury Castle","Bowood","Broad Town White Horse","Caen Locks","Cherhill White Horse","Corsham Court","Devices white Horse","Dragon Hill","Hackpen Hill White Horse","Iford Manor","Lacock","Longleat House","Longleat Safari Park","Marlborough white Horse","Pewsey White Horse","Salisbury Cathedral","Sheldon Manor","Silbury Hill","Stonehenge","The Barge Inn","Uffington White Horse","Westbury White Horse","West Kennet Long Barow","Wilton Windmill","Woodhenge"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Side Menu
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 27
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Locations.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = Locations[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{performSegueWithIdentifier(Locations[indexPath.row], sender:self);
}
}
```

Comment: Your table has 27 sections. From your code snipped it is not clear what you do with that sections. An `indexPath` consists of a section and a row component, where the row starts again with 0 for each section.

Comment: I have now editted the code. Please look it over

Comment: Still unclear: Why 27 sections? You don't care on sections in your data model, neither in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You even don't create the necessery section headers. For me it looks like a flat table with only 1 section.

Comment: How did you create the segues? They need to be ctrl-dragged from the tableViewController icon, NOT from the prototype cells.

Comment: I dragged from the cells themselves. what do you mean the icon? as in the yellow circle with a page in it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have described that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have created the segues the wrong way.

If you have ctrl-dragged a segue from the prototype cell in InterfaceBuilder, this segue is performed without code. Then in your code you call `performSegueWithIdentifier(...)` which causes another segue to trigger.

You need to ctrl-drag all the segues from the tableViewController icon in InterfaceBuilder to the destination viewControllers and then give them the identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

you created a segue with identifier name : **Alton** . Instead of "Alton" you need to rename the Segue identifier as **Alton Barnes White Horse** , later you need to do :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {performSegueWithIdentifier(Locations[indexPath.row], sender:self);
```

Comment: Thanks for help so far this has tidied the code up a lot, rather than needing the massive list of switches. However, When I click on Avebury for example Alton Branes still loads before Avebury. If you then go back it goes, Avebury -> Alton Barnes -> Table view, rather than just Aebury -> Table view. Any ideas on how to get around this? Could it be something to do with Alton Barnes being in the tableviewcell with identifier Cell?

Comment: It is a bad idea to name the seques according to your data strings because the data strings may be completely different in a localized app in different languages.

Comment: Code editted still not working. Please help if you can